# Ansible rollback: run a group of tasks over list of hosts even when one of hosts failed

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook with multiple roles, hosts and groups. I am trying to develop a rollback functionality, that would run over all hosts. My current obstacle is that I see no way to delegate role, block or set of tasks to group of hosts

- I tried looking up delegation to group without loops, so it would work on a block.
- import_role doesn't accept loops
- include_role doesn't accept delegate_to
- same with import_tasks/include_tasks

here is what I have now as a playbook file (shortened version)

```
- hosts: all
  any_errors_fatal: true
  vars_prompt:

  - name: "remote_user_p"
    prompt: "Remote user running the playbook"
    default: "root"
    private: no

  - name: "service_user_p"
    prompt: "Specify user to run non-root tasks"
    default: "user"
    private: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        playbook_type: "upgrade"

    - import_role:
        name: 0_pre_check
      run_once: true
      remote_user: "{{ remote_user_p }}"
      become_user: "{{ service_user_p }}"
      become_method: su
      become: yes

    - block:      
      - import_role:
          name: 1_os

      - import_role:
          name: 2_mysql
        when: inventory_hostname in groups['mysql'] | default("")

      - import_role:
          name: 3_web
        when: inventory_hostname in groups['web'] | default("") 
...

      rescue:
        - block:
          - name: run rollback
            import_tasks: ../common/roles/5_rollback/tasks/rollback.yml

      remote_user: "{{ remote_user }}"
      become_user: "{{ service_user }}"
      become_method: su
      become: yes
```

This is some example code from rollback.yml:

```
- block:
  - name: rollback symlinks to config dir
    file:
      src: "{{ current_config_path }}"
      dest: "{{ install_dir }}/static/cfg"
      owner: "{{ service_user }}"
      group: "{{ service_user_primary_group }}"
      state: link
    when: current_new_configs | default("N") == "Y"
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"

  - block:           
    - name: return config files
      shell: test -f '{{ item.1.current_ver_file_path }}' && cp -p {{ item.1.current_ver_file_path }} {{ item.1.old_config_location }}
      args:
        warn: false
      register: return_config_files
      failed_when: return_config_files.rc >= 2
      when:
        - roolback_moved_cfg | default('N') == "Y"
        - inventory_hostname in groups[item.0.group]
        - item.1.old_config_location != ""
        - item.1.current_ver_file_path != ""
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ config_files }}"
        - files
      become_user: root
      become_method: sudo
      become: yes

    - name: systemctl daemon-reload  
      shell: systemctl daemon-reload
      failed_when: false
      when: root_rights == "Y"
      args:
        warn: false
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
    when: root_rights == "Y"
    become_user: root
    become_method: sudo
    become: yes

  - fail:
      msg: "Upgrade failed. Symbolic links were set to the previous version. Fix the issues and try again. If you wish to cancel the upgrade, restore the database backup manually."
```

As you can see, now I use lame workaround by introducing

```
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```

after every task.

There are two problems here:
1. I can't use same approach after task `return config files`, because it already uses one loop
2. This is generally lame duplication of code and I hate it

Why I need it at all: if playbook execution fails somewhere in `mysql` role, for example, the `rescue` block will be executed only over the hosts in that `mysql` role (and btw, execution of tasks from next role will continue while running rescue block - same amount of tasks, despite all efforts), while I would like it to run over all hosts instead.

Comment: Have you considered having a second play `- hosts: rollback-hosts` and then using [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/add_host_module.html#add-host-module) in the `rescue:` block to to assign all hosts that should be rolled back into that (otherwise empty) group?

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is a new idea to me! The problem here is that I use `any_errors_fatal: true` and second play won't execute with failed task in first, and first play will continue if I don't fail it. 

My goal is to execute tasks on all hosts successfully, and if not - then fail and rollback. This is what I have now:

```
- hosts: all
  any_errors_fatal: true
  tasks:
...
      rescue:
        - block:
          - set_fact:
              foo: "bar"
          - fail:
              msg: "fail"
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to solve this with an ugly-ugly hack. Used plays instead of just roles - now there are more than 10 plays. Don't judge me, I spent lots of effort trying to make it nice ):

Example play followed by a check - same as for every other.

```
- hosts: mysql
  any_errors_fatal: true
  tasks:
    - block:              
      - import_role:
          name: 2_mysql
        when: not rollback | default(false)
      rescue:
        - block:
          - name: set fact for rollback
            set_fact: 
              rollback: "yes"
            delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
            delegate_facts: true
            with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"

- hosts: all
  any_errors_fatal: true
  tasks:
    - name: run rollback
      import_tasks: ../common/roles/5_rollback/tasks/rollback.yml
      when: rollback | default(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

> `include_role` doesn't accept `delegate_to`

Actually, it does.

With ansible-core 2.8:

```
- name: "call my/role with host '{{ansible_hostname}}' for hosts in '{{ansible_play_hosts}}'"
  include_role:
    name: my/role
  apply:
    delegate_to: "{{current_host}}"
  with_items: "{{ansible_play_hosts}}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: current_host
```

With ansible-core 2.5 to 2.7, see "[2.5: delegate_to, include_role with loops](https://medium.com/opsops/ansible-2-5-delegate-to-and-include-role-20cd7e67008e)" from [George Shuklin](https://github.com/amarao), mentioned in [`ansible/ansible` issue 35398](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/35398#issuecomment-381981498)

```
- name: "call my/role with host '{{ansible_hostname}}' for items in '{{ansible_play_hosts}}'"
    include_tasks: loop.yml
    with_items: "{{ansible_play_hosts}}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: current_host
```

With `loop.yml` another tasks in its own file:

```
- name: "Import my/role for '{{current_host}}'"
  import_role: name=my/role
  delegate_to: "{{current_host}}"
```

So in two files (with ansible-core 2.7) or one file (2.8), you can make a all role and its tasks run on a delegated server.